# Oracle view query with one condition based on which data is retrieved but one row is not retrieved

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The Following is the query:

```
    SELECT XALDV.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
              TO_CHAR (XALDV.HIRE_DATE ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
              XALDV.HOLDER_NAME,
              XALDV.BUSINESS_LINE1,
              TO_CHAR (XALDV.ISSUE_DATE ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
              XALDV.LICENSE_DESCRIPTION,
              XALDV.BUSINESS_LINE2,
              XALDV.LICENSE_NO,
              XALDV.BUSINESS_LINE3,
              XALDV.BUSINESS_LINE4,
              XALDV.LICENSE_TITLE,
              XALDV.BUSINESS_LINE5,
              XALDV.LICENSE_TYPE,
              XALDV.LIC_AUTHORITY_NAME,
              XALDV.LIC_CATEGORY_NAME,
              XALDV.LIC_HOLDER_TYPE,
              XALDV.LIC_PROJECT_NAME,
              XALDV.LIC_REGION_NAME,
              XALDV.LIC_STATUS_NAME,
              XALDV.LOA_STATUS,
              XALDV.MASTEC_ORG,
              TO_CHAR (XALDV.RENEWAL_DATE ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
              XALDV.STATE details ,
              null publish_cols
FROM   APPS.XXMTZ_AT_LIC_DTL_V XALDV 
WHERE  1=1
AND   '05-JAN-2019' BETWEEN issue_date AND NVL(RENEWAL_DATE,SYSDATE)
```

The issue that one specific row is not coming is due to null value in Renewal_date.

I've tried using the NVL as it's in my sample code but it doesn't get me that specific row.

Please help me out what can be done?

Comment: is there a value in `issue_date` for that record ? If yes, what is the value

Comment: issue_date also has null value for that specific record.

Comment: so you already have found out the problem with the SQL right ? you need an `NVL` function for your `issue_date` as well. something like `NVL(issue_date, '01-jan-1950')` ?

Comment: I've tried adding NVL to both but the record which i want doesn't come up. The Following is query i used -> :Start_date   BETWEEN  NVL(issue_date, '07-JAN-2019') AND NVL(renewal_date, SYSDATE)

Comment: what is the value of `:start_date` ?

Comment: it's a date value parameter which we dynamically pass a date value to the query.

Comment: I passed sysdate as the value.

Comment: `SYSDATE` will fail because, SYSDATE for today will also have a time associated with it, lets say 2 pm, however in your query, you are comparing `07-JAN-2019 14:00:00` with  `07-JAN-2019 00:00:00. Hence your query is failing. Instead of SYSDATE, you can try `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` so that only the date parameter is sent with time as `00:00:00`

Comment: I tried out doing as you said the count in the retrieval increased but the record which i want didn't come.

Comment: hey! Thanks. It Fixed my issue i was doing it in a wrong way. Thanks @Sudipta Mondal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> issue_date also has null value for that specific record.

You are running the below query

```
select 1 
  from dual
 where '05-JAN-2019' between NULL and NVL(NULL, sysdate)
```

You cannot expect the above to give any records back, since `05-JAN-2019` doesn't fall between `NULL` and any value. It wouldn't even compare as dates, since one of the values to compared is `NULL`.

If you however run the below query, it will give you a record as now you have added the NVL condition to take care of the NULL.

```
select 1 
  from dual
 where date '2019-01-01' between NVL(NULL,'01-jan-1950') and NVL(null, sysdate)
```

Solution for your query is something you need to decide based on the values you are expecting the query to return

```
WHERE  1=1
  AND   '05-JAN-2019' BETWEEN NVL(issue_date,'05-JAN-2019') AND NVL(RENEWAL_DATE,SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `BETWEEN` with dates!  This is particularly important with Oracle, where the `DATE` data type has a time component -- whether you see it or not.

So, I would recommend:

```
( (issue_date IS NULL OR issue_date >= DATE '2019-01-05') AND
  (renewal_date IS NULL OR renewal_date < sysdate)
)
```

Comment: To clarify, you mean to say never use BETWEEN to compare two date columns?

Comment: @Jåcob . . . Yes, that is what I mean.  This blog from Aaron Bertrand is specifically for Oracle (https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  The situation with Oracle is even more compelling than SQL Server, because there is no pure `date` data type.